# Importing multing multiple JSON files in R single dataframe

Tags: r

Hei,
I want to import JSON files from a folder to R data frame (as a single matrix). I have about 40000 JSON files with one observation each and different variable sizes.

I tried following codes

```
library(rjson)
jsonresults_all <- list.files("mydata", pattern="*.json", full.names=TRUE)
 
myJSON <- lapply(jsonresults_all, function(x) fromJSON(file=x)) 

myJSONmat <- as.data.frame(myJSON)
```

I want my data frame something like (40000 observations (rows) and some 175 variables (column) with some variable values NA.
But I get a single row containing each observation appended to the right.
Many thanks for your suggesion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Can you please share an example of e.g. 2-3 of your JSON file after reading them in? E.g. with `dput(jsonresults_all[1:3])`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Or put the `as.data.frame` call inside your `lapply` function.  And then `dplyr::bind_rows()` or `rbind()` the result.